# trying to follow tutorial to make a super simple pygame game and it's not working our code looks identical as far as I can tell

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple little game via pygame I've been following a tutorial and for some reason at this stage it should just open up a black window but for whatever reason it doesn't here is my code

```
import pygame
import sys
import math
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Squid Slayer")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

WIDTH =1200
HEIGHT =800

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#make the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

#Making classes
class Sprite ():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.dx = 0
        self.dy = 0
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = WHITE
        self.friction = 0.8

    def goto(self):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def render(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, pygame.Rect(int(self.x-self.width/2.0),int(self.y-self.height/2.0), self.width, self.height))

    def is_aabb_collision(self, other):
        # Axis Sligned Bounding Box
        x_collision = (math.fabs(self.x-other.x)*2)<(self.width+other.width)
        y_collision = (math.fabs(self.y-other.y)*2)<(self.height+other.height)
        return (x_collision and y_collision)

class Player(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        Sprite.__init__(self, x, y, width, height)

    # Create font

    # Create sounds

    # Create game objects
player = Player(600, 0, 20, 40)
    #Main game loop
    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

                # Keyboard events
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                        pass
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                        pass
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        pass

    # Move/Update objects

    # Check for collisions

    # Border check the player

    # Render (Draw stuff)
    player.render()
    #fill the background color
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    #Render objects

    #Flip the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    #Set the FPS
    clock.tick(30)
```

and here is a link to the tutorial any suggestions are greatly appreciated:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3ri4f7y8uJI

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to me that the `while True:` loop's indentation is one extra tab inside compared to the original code.

Comment: There is a recommendation not to answer typo-question. Questions like these are off-topic and should not be answered but closed as they are not helpful to other contributors. The questions will be closed and finally deleted. If the question is deleted, your gained reputation points will be lost.